# Django: Necessary html-page in views

Tags: python, html, django

Good day everybody, I am trying to make blog on Django and I need help. I need that django render neccesary html-page. For example:

post link: http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/

html link: blog/articles/1.html

What must I write in views.py instead this:

```
def article_detail(request, pk):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/articles/1.html', {'article': article})
```

Comment: Are you getting an error.. Can you provide more information please ? For example can we see the urls.py file

Comment: I need that function article_detail change number here: 'blog/articles/1.html' to necessary number of post. If I try to open post number two, it must change render to 'blog/articles/2.html'.

Comment: You're going to create a html template for each object in the system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the html page is named the same as the pk

```
  return render(request, 'blog/articles/{}.html'.format(pk), {'article': article})
```

I don't recommend a setup like this though. Adding a new html page for each object is redundant. You probably should create one html page that can be reusued for each object.